# Swift - UICollectionViewCells with dynamic height

Tags: swift, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm developing a chat app and I can't figure out how to make the `UICollectionViewCell`s' height dynamic, depending on how large the `UITextView`'s text is.

Here’s what I've been testing;

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var cv: UICollectionView!
    
    let arr = ["hi hello", "func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell", "func collectionView", "// Do any additional setup after loading the view.", "extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        if let flowLayout = cv.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
            flowLayout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        }
        
        // setup cv constraints here
    }

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mm", for: indexPath) as! MessageCollectionViewCell
        cell.setup(text: arr[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

And here's my cell's code;

```
class MessageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var tv: UITextView!
    
    func setup(text: String) {
        tv.text = text
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            tv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            tv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
            tv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
    }
}
```

That's the end result;
[image: screenshot]

Any idea what I’ve been missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it! All I should do, was to add a width constraint to the cell itself, so it wouldn’t get bigger horizontally that it needed!

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   self.contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: maxDeviceWidth)
])
```